# What does "Full Dawn" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, antebellum

Veronica presents a seminar on her book "Shedding the Coping Persona". Later, Bridget
brought her away from Camille:

> Bridget: How often do I get my V? Twice a year? Maybe three times a
> year. Okay, I need you all to myself tonight. Okay? No filter. **Full
> Dawn**.
>
> Veronica: Oh, she comes with a filter?

What does "Full Dawn" mean?

Answer (score 2):

The [script](https://lionsgate.brightspotcdn.com/54/d1/0f4d06ef4ff5aa8563d0d8493474/antebellum.Script.pdf) is worded slightly more comprehensibly. By "*full Dawn*" she means that she can be her true self around Veronica ("*Vee*") without worrying about upsetting her, unlike how she needs to behave in front of her squarer friends.

> **DAWN:** *You are welcome!*
> *Real talk -- she was angling to join us for dinner this evening and I just couldn’t have it.*
> *Girl, bye.*
> *We deserve a little recess from academia. Besides - I only get my Vee* [Veronica] *time a few times a year and I need to be able to be “All Dawn” – no filter.*
>
> **VERONICA:** (playfully) *There’s a filter?* (slight pause)
> *So is Sarah locked in a closet somewhere as well?*